# How to add 14 based numbers in instance method?

Tags: java, class, instance

So I'm having trouble with creating an instance method to add two 14-based number and I was wondering if anyone could help? I'm a bit new to java and still sort of confused on the whole thing. So far I have the code to convert the 14-based numbers to base 10 then I need to add them and convert them back to base-14. I want to put them all in once instance class, but I feel like it's too much to put into one instance class.

This is the kind of input I was for the client code to be like this:

> PokerNum sum = num1.add(num2);

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class PokerNum{

  String alienNum;
  int num1, num2;

   public PokerNum(String alienNum) throws IllegalArgumentException{
   this.alienNum = alienNum;
   String toUpper = alienNum.toUpperCase();
   for (int i = 0; i < toUpper.length(); i++){
    char c = toUpper.charAt(i);
     if (!(Character.isDigit(c) || c == 'A' || c == 'J' || c == 'Q' || c == 'K')){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid input"); 
      }
  }
}


  // initialized at zero 
  public PokerNum() {
  this.num1=0;
  this.num2=0;

  }

    @Override public String toString(){
    return PokerNum()+ " ";
     }

  //add pokernums
  public PokerNum add(PokerNum another){
     PokerNum num = new PokerNum();
     this.num1 = another.num1;
     this.num2 = another.num2;

  public PokerNum convert(PokerNum pn){
     char[] firstNum = num1.toCharArray();
     int amountValue = 0;
     int length = characters.length;
     for (int index = 0; index < length; index++){
        int symbolValue;
        switch (characters[index]) {
           case 'A':
              symbolValue = 10; 
              break;
           case 'J':
              symbolValue = 11;
              break;
           case 'Q':
              symbolValue = 12;
              break;
           case 'K': 
              symbolValue= 13;
              break;
           default: 
              symbolValue = characters[index] - 48;
     }
     amountValue += symbolValue*Math.pow(14, length - index - 1);
  }



     StringBuilder result1 = new StringBuilder();
     while(amountValue > 0){
        int digit = amountValue%14;
        switch (digit) {
           case 10:
              result.insert(0, 'A');
              break;
           case 11:
              result.insert(0, 'J');
              break; 
           case 12:
              result.insert(0, 'Q');
              break;
           case 13:
              result.insert(0, 'K');
              break; 
           default:
              result.insert(0, digit);
     }
     amountValue-=digit;
     amountValue/=14;
     String firstValue = result1.toString();
  }
}






     char[] secNum = num2.toCharArray();
     int amountValue2= 0;
     int length = secNum.length;
     for (int index = 0; index < length; index++){
        int symbolValue;
        switch (characters[index]) {
           case 'A':
              symbolValue = 10; 
              break;
           case 'J':
              symbolValue = 11;
              break;
           case 'Q':
              symbolValue = 12;
              break;
           case 'K': 
              symbolValue= 13;
              break;
           default: 
              symbolValue = characters[index] - 48;
     }
     amountValue2+= symbolValue*Math.pow(14, length - index - 1);
  }

     StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
     while(amountValue2> 0){
        int digit = amountValue%14;
        switch (digit) {
           case 10:
              result.insert(0, 'A');
              break;
           case 11:
              result.insert(0, 'J');
              break; 
           case 12:
              result.insert(0, 'Q');
              break;
           case 13:
              result.insert(0, 'K');
              break; 
           default:
              result.insert(0, digit);
     }
     amountValue2-=digit;
     amountValue2/=14;
     PokerNum secondValue = result.toString();
  }
  return firstValue + secondValue; 









   /*PokerNum sum = num1 + 
  PokerNum another.num2 = 





  return sum;*/
 }
```

Thanks to anyone who helps in advance :)

Comment: If your code is already working, and you just want some pointers on how you might refactor it, then consider migrating your question to our sister site, [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Well, the thing is it's not working in the way it should.  I think it's appropriate for it to be on here.

Comment: @Quin your code has compilation Errors Could you update the code?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can keep it in one instance.  One suggestion is to use the conversion using the following functions:

```
Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)
Integer.toString(int i, int radix)
```

The javadoc says that the string produced will use:

> 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

So, if we choose radix = 14, it will have 0123456789abcd.

The logic idea is to keep the actual number as `int`, and to convert at creation and at printout from and to String.  We can just keep member variable `num1` and remove the member variable `alienNum` and `num2`.

**Constructor**

Your constructor with String argument seems to do a good error checking.  What we need here is just to convert from string to integer and store it in the member variable.  First we need to convert all valid string from `AJQK` to `ABCD`.  The example here is inefficient, but gets the idea across:

```
//alienNum = alienNum.replace('A', 'A'); // no need
alienNum = alienNum.replace('J', 'B');
alienNum = alienNum.replace('Q', 'C');
alienNum = alienNum.replace('K', 'D');
```

Then we can call the parsing method:

```
num1 = Integer.parseInt(alienNum , 14);
```

Your empty arg constructor is already fine by initializing the value of `num1` to 0.

**Adding**

The method inside addition is not right because it is setting the current value to the addition.  There are three objects working here:  `num`, `this`, and `another`.  You want to add `this` to `another` into `num` and return `num`.

```
num.num1 = this.num1 + another.num1;
```

**Output**

I'm assuming the output is going to be from `toString()`.  In this case, you want to convert from integer to string, then convert it to the right character

```
String out = Integer.toString(num1, 14).toUpper();
//alienNum = alienNum.replace('A', 'A'); // no need
alienNum = alienNum.replace('B', 'J');
alienNum = alienNum.replace('C', 'Q');
alienNum = alienNum.replace('D', 'k');
```

You probably won't need a convert method now.